# Sjasm: can't assemble DW or OUTPUT directive?

Tags: assembly, z80

This is my code:

```
output "ejemplo1.bin"

db #fe
dw START
dw END

org #8500

START:
    ld a, [#8600]
    ld b, a
    ld a, [#8601]
    add a, b
    ld [#8602], a

    ret
```

END:
And this is what I'm getting when trying to compile it:

```
C:\Users\Daniel\Programming\MSX\asm>sjasm ejemplo1.asm
Sjasm Z80 Assembler v0.42c - www.xl2s.tk
ejemplo1.asm(1) : Unrecognized instruction: "ejemplo1.
ejemplo1.asm(3) : Label not found: fe
ejemplo1.asm(4) : Unrecognized instruction: start
ejemplo1.asm(5) : Duplicate labelname: dw
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the sjasm manual say that `dw` is supposed to work, or how to use `output`?  Also, `#fe` appears to be getting interpreted as a symbol name.  I don't know what Z80 assemblers normally use to indicate hex literal immediates, whether it's`#0xfe`, `#$fe`, or `#0feH`, but if the manual doesn't describe the syntax, that's what I'd try first.  (But generally it's not a good idea to throw syntax at the wall and see what sticks, especially with assembly where "happens to work" doesn't always mean "correct".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps if you read the [manual](http://www.xl2s.tk/sjasmmanual.html).

**The main error:** Only labels start in the first column, insert at least a space or tab before any instruction or pseudo instruction.

> ejemplo1.asm(1) : Unrecognized instruction: "ejemplo1.

`output` is interpreted as label, and consequently the filename is tried as an instruction. The interesting detail is that the point "." is taken as a separator. BTW, the filename is not in quotation marks, according to the examples.

> ejemplo1.asm(3) : Label not found: fe

`db` is interpreted as label, and perhaps `#fe` is interpreted as a structure field entry. `#` defines the length on a field, and therefore `fe` is not recognized as a number, but as a label. This interpretation looks like a bug in the assembler to me.

> ejemplo1.asm(4) : Unrecognized instruction: start

`dw` is interpreted as label, and consequently `start` is tried as an instruction.

> ejemplo1.asm(5) : Duplicate labelname: dw

`dw` is again interpreted as label, as the error message tells us that it is already defined (in the line before).

*Note: If you correct your code and get new errors, feel free to post a new question. You might want to add this to this question, **but don't remove the current contents**, add it and mark it as addition.*